# Is loop possible to implemented in Merge statement and commit in every 6000 rows

Tags: db2

sample merge statement as below

```
 MERGE INTO table_to_upsert AS tab
 USING (SELECT * FROM B
     ) merge
     ON tab.key_to_match = merge.key_to_match 
     WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET tab.C1 = merge.C1,
                    tab.C2 = merge.C2,
                    tab.C3 = merge.C3
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT (C1, C2, C3)
         VALUES (merge.C1, merge.C2, merge.C3)
```

Is there any way to run the merge statement in a loop and apply commit on every 6000 rows ..

trying to implement above sql, instead to commit all the rows at a time , is there any way to commit for every 6000 rows.. ?

Comment: It would require you to write that logic. Have you considered INGEST? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0057198.html

Comment: @data_henrik .. Thank you for the reply. Not aware of Ingest . If there is any sample syntax can you help me with the webpage or any other reference..

Comment: You mean more than the many samples statements included in the docs? Anything specific?

Comment: @data_henrik .. Like an example Sql statement to run a loop using merge , so that as per the requirement i will try to modify.

Comment: as stated, I would use INGEST

Comment: @data_henrik .. through Ingest can we specify the number of rows to be committed when trying to run the Merge

Comment: @data_henrik .. as suggested,  when i see the above link  Ingest is mostly used to load the data from a file to a table but i am trying to find a way to write a statement with Source & target as tables and specify number of rows to be committed and print the log.

Comment: @data_henrik Ingest is not going to help me in this scenario..

Answer (score 1):

You may use a compound sql to organize a loop on `B` records.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
BEGIN
  DECLARE L_COMMIT_SIZE INT DEFAULT 6000;
  DECLARE L_COMMIT_CNTR INT DEFAULT 0;

  FOR V AS CUR CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT key_to_match, c1 FROM B
  DO
    MERGE INTO table_to_upsert t
     USING TABLE(VALUES (V.key_to_match, V.c1)) m (key_to_match, c1)
     ON t.key_to_match = m.key_to_match 
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET C1 = m.C1
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (key_to_match, C1) VALUES (V.key_to_match, V.c1);

    SET L_COMMIT_CNTR = L_COMMIT_CNTR + 1;
    IF L_COMMIT_SIZE = L_COMMIT_CNTR THEN
      COMMIT;
      SET L_COMMIT_CNTR = 0;
    END IF;
  END FOR;
  COMMIT;   
END
@
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply .. 

Can i make the statement like below 

USING TABLE(VALUES (V.key_to_match, V.c1)) m (key_to_match, c1)

---->

USING (select * from B) m

Comment: No, you can't. How do you think, why I wrote a small sub-program instead of a single statement, if it would be possible to do this? The main problem is that you can't make a single statement to commit its work by some parts. So, the only solution for your case is to make N statements each operating on subset of rows returned by `SELECT * FROM B`. If you want to do the work with a smaller number of statements, then you must create a loop and with merge on `SELECT * FROM B WHERE ID BETWEEN x AND y`, choosing x and y every time to cover next interval of rows. But it's more complex algorithm.